# IP allocation for a virtual network gateway in azure by using a dynamic block in terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-provider-gcp

How we can dynamically pass the values to a resource block in terraform through .tfvar files from a core module through a child module.
There are 2 modules 1) core module and 2) calling module

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "this" {
  name                = var.name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.rg
  type                = var.type
  sku                 = var.sku

  dynamic "ip_configuration" {
    for_each = var.ip_config
    content {
    name                          = ip_configuration.value.name
    public_ip_address_id          = ip_configuration.value.address_id
    subnet_id                     = ip_configuration.value.subnet_id
    }
  }
}
```

```
variable "ip_config" {
  type = map(object({
    name       = string
    address_id = string
    subnet_id  = string
  }))
}
```

calling module code:

```
module "vnet_gw" {
source = ""
for_each = var.vnet_gw 
  name = each.value.name
  .
  .
  .
  ip_config = {
    ipconfig_name        = each.value.ip_config.ip_name
    public_ip_address_id = each.value.ip_config.addr_id
    subnet_id            = each.value.ip_config.s_id
  }
}
```

variable.tf file for the calling module.

```
ip_config = list(object({

  ipconfig_name        = string
  public_ip_address_id = string
  subnet_id            = string

}))
```

The tf var file to pass the values. The Ip section need to add multiple section.

```
vnet_gw {
  "vnet1" = {
    name : ""
    rg : ""
    .
    .
    .
  ip_config = {
    "ip_1" : {
      ip_name              = "test1"
      addr_id              = "<id>"
      s_id                 = "<id>"
  },
    "ip_2" : {
       ip_name              = "test2"
       addr_id              = "<id>"
       s_id                 = "<id>"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

How ever getting the below error on execution plan

> on main.tf line , in module "vnet_gw":
> each.value.ip_config is map of object with 2 elements
> This map does not have an element with the key "ip_name"
> similar for public address id and subnet_id

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: The code in the question does not match the error. Please add the **current** version of the code you are using.

Comment: The error is each.value.ip_config  in main.tf is a map of object with 2 elements 
This map does not have an element with the key "ip_name", "addr_id" and "s_id"

Comment: The way you are using your code right now would require you to use `each.value.ip_config.ip_1.ip_name` and the same for the resto of the values. That would have to be repeated for `ip_2` key.

Comment: A bit more explanation to what Marko wrote: The variable `ip_config` is a map of objects but you do not use it as a map in your code. Instead of `each.value.ip_config.ip_name`, you need to either use a key for `each.value.ip_config` or change the variable `ip_config` to a object (without the map).

Comment: @MarkoE :  if we use "each.value.ip_config.ip_1.ip_name " then this has to update in the calling modules for n number of ip configs. Can we pass the values from the tf vars itself without changing the modules. 
for eg : if we give 3 "ip_config" from tf.vars.

Comment: @DirkR This has to be map of object as we have passing the more than one section of IP config from the tfvar files

Comment: @rravinda will the current IP configuration be valid only for `vnet1`?

Comment: @MarkoE yes, now it is only valid for "vnet_gw" keys in tfvars, but there will be more keys for vnetgateway with multiple ip configurations